# Event Listeners e manipulação direta de Event Propagation

Tags: php, eventos, engenharia-de-software

Minhas incursões recentes em termos de desenvolvimento PHP foram com respeito a *Event Handling* e *Event Listening*.

Através de um [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) foi possível criar uma plataforma concisa e elegante para elevar a extensibilidade a outro nível.

Assim como no Javascript, todo *Event Listener* recebe no mínimo um [Evento](https://github.com/nextframework/next/blob/dev/Components/Events/Event.php) para ser manipulado em seus próprios escopos:

```
$eventHandler -> addListener(

    'success', new Listener( function( Event $event, View $view, $message ) {

        $view -> success = $message;
    })
);

$eventHandler -> addListener(

    'error', new Listener( function( Event $event, View $view, $message ) {

        $event -> stopPropagation();

        $view -> error = $message;
    })
);
```

Esses são dois exemplos reais implementados como parte dos *Listeners* padrão de uma classe base para desenvolvimento de [Plugins](https://github.com/nextframework/next/blob/dev/Components/Plugin.php)

São bem simples pois eles apenas fornecem informações à Aplicação onde os Plugins serão utilizados, evitando-se assim dezenas de IFs aninhados apenas para montar uma simples View.

Bem, como no JavaScript, os Eventos manipuláveis de dentro dos *Listeners* podem ter sua propagação interrompida. E tal recurso também foi implementado fazendo com que caso os *Listeners* acima fossem usados da seguinte forma:

```
$application = new Application; # Fake
$view = new View; # Fake

$plugin = new Plugin( $application );

$plugin -> getEventHandler() -> handle( 'error', $view, 'message' );
$plugin -> getEventHandler() -> handle( 'warning', $view, 'message' );
```

Apenas o *Listener* de erro seria executado. pois o processo de disparo seria abortado caso o Evento tivesse tido sua propagação interrompida.

Pois bem, ocorreu que durante a reescrita dos Plugins, tanto para que passassem a usar a classe base Plugins (que antes era uma interface) como também os *Event Listeners*, eu tive uma epifania (nossa que profundo).

Em conversa recente [no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18992062#18992062) com o @Omni tive como confirmação que, num cenário hipotético, com uma relação 1:N entre dois assuntos, onde cada Plugin seria um dos muitos relacionáveis (N), caso o Plugin tivesse sua tarefa principal executada com sucesso, o Controller que executou o Plugin é quem deveria mudar uma *fag* no banco de dados que caracteriza que tal etapa, de tal Plugin, foi concluída.

Mas e se, apesar de o Plugin ter sido executado com sucesso, essa atualização de *flag* por algum motivo falhasse?

Da mesma forma que um *Listener* de sucesso, um *Listener* de aviso poderia ser disparado em sequência mas, **se** por algum motivo a propagação do Evento tivesse sido impedida no *Listener* de sucesso, o *Listener* sequencial seria ignorado.

E é aí que entra minha epifania:

> Seria minimamente plausível operar manualmente, em escopo global, o Evento ora manipulado no escopo local de um *Listener* para que, quando um próximo fosse disparado ele não fosse restringido pela propagação interrompida no *Listener* anterior?

Minha idéia, atualmente implementada e plenamente funcional foi algo assim, apesar de bastante resumida e abstraída (mas logicamente equivalente):

```
class Controller {

    private $application;
    private $view;

    // ...

    public function action() {

        $plugin = new Plugin( $this -> application );

        try {

            // Executes pre-execution routines

            $plugin -> onBeforeRun();

            // Main routine

            $plugin -> run();

            /*
             * Executes post-execution routines
             * Here is where the success Listener is
             * triggered and the Event Propagation stopped
             */
            $plugin -> onAfterRun();

            // Updates Plugin status

            try {

                // ...

                $repository -> update();

            } catch( SomeTableException $e ) {

                // Manuall restarting the Event Propagation

                $plugin -> getEventHandler() -> getEvent() -> startPropagation();

                $plugin -> getEventHandler() -> handle(

                    'warning', $this -> view, $e -> getMessage()
                );
            }

        } catch( SomePLuginException $e ) {

            // Plugin execution error. Handled differently
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Ou seja, assumindo que o Plugin tenha sido executado com sucesso mas que por algum motivo, perfeitamente falsificável a título de depuração, a entidade do repositório não tenha podido ser atualizada, outro *Listener* seria executado apenas para avisar que *quase* tudo correu bem, mas, para isso, a propagação do Evento interrompida pelo Listener anterior deveria ser revertida.

Mas, até o momento, não encontrei nada respeito, nem mesmo em JavaScript para saber se existiria essa possibilidade e/ou se faria sentido o empreendimento.

Comment: Me esclareça uma coisa: seu evento propaga por onde? Pela pilha de funções? Porque no caso do JS a propagação é pelo DOM, mas no PHP não entendi onde seria.

Comment: Algo automático no estilo do DOM seria bastante complicado com PHP, então é pseudo-automático. No exemplo que eu dei, o Listener de sucesso é disparado em Plugin::onAfterRun() que é invocado após o Plugin ter sido executado com sucesso, já que, se houver um erro, o fluxo é direcionado para o bloco catch mais externo.